# Resource leak: 'input' is never closed

Tags: java

From the code below "Resource leak: 'input' is never closed" remains

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultipleAdder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("정수를 몇 개 더하시겠습니까? ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print(n + "개의 정수를 차례로 입력하시오: ");
        int i;
        int sum = 0;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            sum = sum + input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("정수의 합 = " + sum);
        input.close();
    }
}
```

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCcmd.png)

I closed it after using scanner but it keeps happening resource leak. I know there's no problem running code(if it's as simple as this) but it's too jarring for me.

My professor and assistant inquired, but I didn't get a useful answer and my professor speculated that it might be a compiler problem.

Comment: The above being said, you **don't** want to close a resource wrapping around `System.in`.

Comment: The warning continues to be emitted because you haven't _guaranteed_ the resource will be closed in all cases, normal and exceptional. But you should ignore the warning in this case. Closing your scanner will close the underlying standard input stream as well, and it is rare to want to close standard input (if ever).

Comment: why don't you close your input right after int n = input.nextInt();? You use it for your calculation in the for loop, but you could avoid doin that by saving it to another variable.

Comment: @MrIrrelevant because that's useless. Warnings are useful, but they shouldn't be acted upon just to make them shut up. In this specific case the correct action is "just ignore it".

Answer (score -3):

The java [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class implements the AutoClosable interface.  So is a better approach to use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.htm) to close in case of any problem as the origin of the problem is that your code has several points of failure (in the  [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) methods) that without a try-catch exits the flow without closing the resources. Check the [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) method as it could have an exception if the input is not a number (as example). The IDE is warning you about this case of not controlled exit. You could ignore, but is better to cover the exception cases with the input to close the resource scanner in a grecefuly manner.

Could be changed to:

```
package week2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultipleAdder {


    public static void main( String[] args) {
        try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)){
            System.out.print(" some text");
            int n = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(n + " Some text");
            int i;
            int sum = 0;
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
                sum = sum + input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("some text" + sum);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is why you're getting downvoted but *"a concatenation of strings plus a variable is not recommended (ej. it's not null safe )"* is not true. neither `null + "hello"` or `"hello" + null` throw an exception. Also, there's nothing in the code that could be `null` *and* end up in a string concatenation.

Comment: This doesn't appear to understand the question. It seems to be some general overview without addressing the specific problem.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes, you are right. If we assume a "modern" Java version and not sctrict support the string concatenation of primitives and derivates is safe. I will edit (im an oldy in java and sometimes assume a wider scope, now obsolete. Sorry). But in terms of code guides is not a good approach to use string concatenations.

Comment: @matt why? It's mainly address exactly the problem "Resource leak: 'input' is never closed" in first instance. As nextInt  could raise an exeption if the input data is not a number (ex) and my recommendation is to use a try-with-resources to close at any case the Scanner. It's exactly the problem.

Comment: It doesn't mention that it is a warning at all. You're offering advice that was never good, not just outdated.  "The origin of the problem is that your code has several points of failure that without a try-catch exits the flow without closing the resources." There is no problem, it is a warning from the IDE.

Comment: " So first of all is a better approach to use a try-with-resources" no it is not. Don't close System.in. Why would you close System.in? There is no context to your answer.

Comment: @matt. Please Read the second line. As there are multiple nextInt() that cause the problem as i explain. Sorry if my english is not soo good. It's my third language but you could improve the answer, add tips, comments or suggests edits before declare it a bad response and unuseful at all. That action does not benefict the comunnity and is so condescendent.

Comment: I didn't complain about your english. You answer is not good because it doesn't address the issue. Closing the Scanner is a bad suggestion. "The IDE is warning you about this case of not controlled exit." that is wrong OP never closes it, nextInt doesn't change that, all of the exceptions it declares are `RuntimeException`s.

Comment: " It's mainly address exactly the problem" no, it is very tangential. Yes if you use try-with-resources the warning goes away, but there was no reason why.

Answer (score -3):

As people mentioned it, it's just a warning generated by your IDE and it will perhaps never happen. But if you really want this warning to disappear, you have to cover all the condition in which the close will produce.

So you can change your code like this below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultipleAdder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("정수를 몇 개 더하시겠습니까? ");
            int n = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print(n + "개의 정수를 차례로 입력하시오: ");
            int i;
            int sum = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                sum = sum + input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("정수의 합 = " + sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Using try, it will implicitly call close() method on input after the code is executed.

Comment: Do you really want to close System.in?